# prestashop how to change 'Shopping Cart' to 'Shopping Cart (n)'

Tags: prestashop, shopping-cart

I use PrestaShop 1.7.7.1

Right now: [image]
How can I do this? [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit themes<your_theme>\templates\checkout\cart.tpl

Calculate number of products in cart controller and assign it to smarty variable.

And use the variable in above smarty tpl file.